# AMCL + Robot_localization conflicts in TF with Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to fuse AMCL pose with imu and odom in Gazebo for a classic mobile manipulator. The mobile manipulator has diff_drive_controller to publish odom topic (/robot_base_velocity_controller/odom)

My mobile manipulator does not define base_footprint, so I use base_link instead.

My knowledge to tf is that, map->odom->base_link->other links, AMCL will deal with map->odom part, and ekf_localization_node deal with the odom->base_link part, and robot_state_publisher deal with other links.

But roswtf would give off below error:

```
ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/base_to_odom_ekf] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/gazebo]
 * node [/gazebo] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/base_to_odom_ekf]
```

Is there a way to turn off robot_state_publisher for a certain tf? Or I configured the tf wrong.

In main.launch file:

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" 
    type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen">
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="base_to_odom_ekf">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odom" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find postoffice_sim)/config/ekf/base_to_odom.yaml" />
</node>
```

base_to_odom.yaml:

```
frequency: 50
two_d_mode: true
odom0: /robot_base_velocity_controller/odom
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
                true,  true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]

imu0: imu_data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false,  true,
              false, false, false]

pose0: amcl_pose
pose0_config: [true,  true,  true,
               true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
publish_tf: true
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411483/amcl-+-robot_localization-conflicts-in-tf-with-gazebo/) by [Li-Wei Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/134452/li-wei-yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/noetic-devel/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L251

Seems like setting `enable_odom_tf` to false in your URDF under the diff drive controller plugin.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Li-Wei Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/134452/li-wei-yang/) on 2023-01-18**:
Thank you, this solves my problem.
It turns out that in my launch file, I loaded .yaml for params

```
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_description)/config/control.yaml" />
  <node name="base_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="robot_base_joint_publisher robot_base_velocity_controller" />
```

So simply change URDF is not enough, for others' reference.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-01-19**:
@Li-Wei Yang Is your project open-sourced and/or available to check online?

**Comment by [Li-Wei Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/134452/li-wei-yang/) on 2023-01-21**:
I just push it to GitHub.
https://github.com/liver121888/postoffice_sim
The manipulator is from chapter 5 of
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ROS-Robotics-Projects-SecondEdition
I made a lot of changes, though, cuz the original code is a mess and uncomplete.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-01-22**:
@Li-Wei Yang Thank you